# How to order by calculated property of included model in Sequelize

Tags: include, sequelize.js

This is my code: (I get longitude and latitude as arguments)

```
var attributes = Object.keys(models.addresses.attributes),    
                distance = Sequelize.fn(    
                    "distance",    
                    longitude,     
                    latitude,     
                    Sequelize.col("longitude"),    
                    Sequelize.col("latitude")     
                )     
            attributes.push([distance, 'distance'])     
const cars = await models.cars.findAll({     
                include: [{     
                    model: models.addresses,     
                    // order: ['car_address->distance'],     
                    as: 'car_address'    
                }],     
                order: 'distance',     
                ...
```

As you can see I'm trying to order by distance between the given coordinate and the coordinate of the address found in the included car_address object (association is defined in the model). However, I cannot get this code to work.. I've tried calculating the distance within the findAll() function, I've tried every possibility of getting the distance attribute.